# Swipeable Recycler View listener overriden by view pager's

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using the [this](https://github.com/brnunes/SwipeableRecyclerView) library (swipeableRecyclerView)

The CardView when swiped moves a little distance and then the fragment starts moving.

i.e. To a point RecyclerView listener implemented with library's callback works and then viewPager's swipe comes into action.

Is there someway of overcoming this situation? I have 2 fragments, so I want to do something like:

right swipe - RecyclerView listener is called and CardView is dismissed
left swipe - viewPager scroll is called and fragments are swiped.

Code:

```
SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener swipeTouchListener =
                new SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener(rv,
                        new SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener.SwipeListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean canSwipe(int position) {
                                return true;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onDismissedBySwipeLeft(RecyclerView recyclerView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                                for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
                                    messages.remove(numbers.get(position));
                                    numbers.remove(position);
                                    adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
                                }
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onDismissedBySwipeRight(RecyclerView recyclerView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                                for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
                                    messages.remove(numbers.get(position));
                                    numbers.remove(position);
                                    adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
                                }
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        });

        rv.addOnItemTouchListener(swipeTouchListener);
```

Comment: Subclass `ViewPager` and override `canScroll()`. If nothing else, you can return `true` when the supplied `View` is your `RecyclerView`, so horizontal gestures over the `RecyclerView` aren't stolen by the `ViewPager`. [Here is a sample app of mine](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/Pager) that demonstrates this in the context of having maps inside of pages of a `ViewPager`.

Comment: It worked but the problem reversed. I have recyclerview in both the frags and Custom viewPager is returning true for both the views i.e. pager is not scrolling but cards are being swiped out. I could leave it at this (user clicks on tab to switch) but it won't be a good design. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question. As shared by CommonsWare, I created custom View Pager but faced the reverse problem (viewpager won't swipe and cards would).

So I made some more tweaks to custom viewPager :

```
public class MyViewPager extends ViewPager {
    public MyViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean canScroll(View v, boolean checkV, int dx, int x,
                                int y) {
        if (v instanceof MyRecyclerView) {
            if(dx>0)
                return(super.canScroll(v, checkV, dx, x, y));
            else
            return(true);
        }

        return(super.canScroll(v, checkV, dx, x, y));
    }
}
```

MyReceyclerView is my custom RecyclerView being used in one fragment. dx>0 ensures that if im coming from right frag to left one viewPager listener is called else cards are swiped away (deleted) from left to right.

Outcome: ViewPager working as intended, simultaneously Cards being swiped/dismissed by users. Thanks CommonsWare.